# How to inherit a variable in Polymer?

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I have the following HTML.

```
<iron-pages id="pages" role="main" selected="[[_page]]" attr-for-selected="name">

    <marked-element name="[[_page]]">
        <div slot="markdown-html"></div>
        <script type="text/markdown" src="/src/markdown/[[_page]].md"></script>
    </marked-element>

</iron-pages>
```

The `[[_page]]` variable works fine except as `src` value. The result is: `marked-element.html:315 GET http://localhost:8081/src/markdown/.md 404 (Not Found)`

How can I make `marked-element` inherit the `_page` variable?

Comment: wouldn't be better to create script tag in javascript and then append it at the end of body? Another way, use `<script ...>` inside file `marker-element`  where you can simply use binding to `name` instead of `_page`  like: `<script type="text/markdown" src="/src/markdown/[[name]].md"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymer does not allow to create/append strings inline so you have to create a new variable with the complete string in it. Also if you want to write something in a default html attribute like src you have to add a $ to its name.

```
<script type="text/markdown" src$="[[_url]]"></script>

//Somewhere in your component
this.set('_url', '/src/markdown/' + this._page + '.md');
```